# AWS iOS SDK: Using both S3 and Mobile Analytics in two different regions

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ios

I am trying to integrate both S3 and Mobile Analytics, using AWS iOS SDK v2, in my *Swift* project. The issue is that I am trying to use two different regions (I am working with my main region, eu-west-1 in Ireland, but Mobile Analytics is [only available from us-east-1 in Virginia](https://aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/faqs/?nc2=h_ls#product-details)).

I have the following in my AppDelegate to initialize Mobile Analytics:

```
    let credentialsProviderForMobileAnalytics = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType(
        AWSRegionType.USEast1,
        accountId: "my_account_id",
        identityPoolId: "pool_id",
        unauthRoleArn: "XXX",
        authRoleArn: "XXX"
    )

    let awsConfigurationForMobileAnalytics = AWSServiceConfiguration(
        region: AWSRegionType.USEast1,
        credentialsProvider: credentialsProviderForMobileAnalytics
    )

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().setDefaultServiceConfiguration(awsConfigurationForMobileAnalytics)
    var mobileAnalytics = AWSMobileAnalytics(forAppId: "MyAwsAppId")
```

Then, in a function called from a ViewController, where I want to upload an image to S3, I have:

```
    let credentialsProviderForS3 = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType(
        AWSRegionType.EUWest1,
        accountId: "my_account_id",
        identityPoolId: "pool_id",
        unauthRoleArn: "XXX",
        authRoleArn: "XXX"
    )

    let awsConfigurationForS3 = AWSServiceConfiguration(
        region: AWSRegionType.EUWest1,
        credentialsProvider: credentialsProviderForS3
    )

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().setDefaultServiceConfiguration(awsConfigurationForS3)

    var transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()

    var fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("temp"))
    var uploadRequest1 : AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()

        uploadRequest1.bucket = "mybucket"
        uploadRequest1.key =  "my-image.jpeg"
        uploadRequest1.body = fileURL
        var task = transferManager.upload(uploadRequest1)
```

If I comment one of the above two sections, the corresponding task gets completed perfectly (when the code for analytics is commented, s3 works and vice versa), but it won't work together - I suspect this is because I am setting the default service configuration using `AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().setDefaultServiceConfiguration()` and the fact that I use two different regions somehow messes up everything. Either it refuses to log the events to Mobile Analytics, or it will interrupt the upload with the error message

> NSUnderlyingError=0x17424ee20 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1001.)",
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/my-image.jpeg})

I tried setting the transfer manager for S3 like this (and commenting the `setDefaultServiceConfiguration` above):

```
    var transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager(configuration: awsConfigurationForS3, identifier: "S3")
```

which results in the following error during uploading:

> "Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 0.)\" UserInfo=0x1742e7e00 {HostId=sm4qLUbN2XfkNYefbSU4A95UXTwvNYEBz0+bALqeFzlcXJ7rOGWnr1Yg+8HoU4r2, Bucket=mybucket, Endpoint=mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com, Message=The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint., Code=PermanentRedirect, RequestId=568728899BC328B0}"

I also tried passing "mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com" as bucket name, but this resulted in an error stating the bucket was not found.

I am really not sure what to try next. Hope you guys can give me some pointers on how to separate those two integrations, and get both working simultaneously.

Comment: My next step would be setting up an S3 bucket in Virginia to see if the two work together if the location is the same.

Comment: Hi @MirekE, thank you so much for your reply. I have created a separate bucket with a new cognito identity pool in us-east-1, and now it is working, as I expected. It is really not ideal that the bucket is located in us-east-1, because my whole setup is in eu-west-1, and all of our users are located in western europe. Do you have any idea how I can achieve having both mobile analytics and s3 in my preferred region that is not the same as for mobile analytics? Thanks again for your reply and your time !

Comment: Perhaps Amazon AWS support might help?

Comment: I have posted this problem to AWS community forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=604250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the S3 region to `USEast1`, yet your bucket is in `EUWest1`. Based on the log, you are setting `USEast1` to the `awsConfigurationForS3` object in the following code snippet:

```
var transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager(configuration: awsConfigurationForS3, identifier: "S3")
```

You should update the S3 region to `EUWest1` (you can also update the Cognito Identity region to `EUWest1` as well). Try the following code snippet:

```
// You can use the new constructor with fewer arguments.
let credentialsProviderForS3 = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType(
    AWSRegionType.EUWest1,
    identityPoolId: "pool_id"
)

let awsConfigurationForS3 = AWSServiceConfiguration(
    region: AWSRegionType.EUWest1,
    credentialsProvider: credentialsProviderForS3
)

// You need to retain a strong reference to an instance of AWSS3TransferManager until `- upload:` finishes executing. Making it a property is one way to do this.
self.transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager(configuration: awsConfigurationForS3, identifier: "S3")

var fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("temp"))
var uploadRequest1 : AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest1.bucket = "mybucket"
uploadRequest1.key =  "my-image.jpeg"
uploadRequest1.body = fileURL

// `- upload:` is an asynchronous request. This means you need to retain a strong reference to `transferManager` until the async call completes.
transferManager.upload(uploadRequest1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yosuke, but as you can see in my second code snippet, it seems that the region is already set to `EUWest1`... What should I try next? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi Yosuke, thank you so much for your updated answer. It fixed my problem, I can now log analytics to USEast1 and use S3 in EUWest1 region at the same time. Thanks again, AWS rocks! :-)